# Is there a way to exit demo mode on the PS4 kiosk?

Tags: psn, ps4

I recently got the demo model of the PS4 from a closing Target store in Canada. Unfortunately I can't seem to switch to normal mode. I tried formatting the HDD and then initializing it, but no use, it still goes into kiosk mode. I can go into "Staff Mode" but can't do much there. The model is a CUH-1001A which is a retail model.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: did you try to reinstall the whole fw? and which current fw you got on it?

Comment: Did you download a fresh install file from Sony? https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps4/

Comment: How is this unreleased and illegal content?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. To get out of the demo/kiosk mode, you'll need a Firmware-Reverter like for the good old PS3 which is not possible for now because there isn't such a thing for the PS4 so far. However i'm not sure if such questions are allowed here because it's not about a game and what you're asking about is **against** [Sonys software lisence agreement](http://www.scei.co.jp/ps4-eula/ps4_eula_en.html).

> You may not (i) use any unauthorized, illegal, counterfeit or modified
>   hardware or software with System Software; (ii) use tools to bypass,
>   disable or circumvent any PS4 system encryption, security or
>   authentication mechanism; **(iii) reinstall earlier versions of the
>   System Software ("downgrading")**;

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to contact Sony and ask them - Demo consoles aren't normally owned by the store, they are on a free rental deal from the manufacturers, so the only people who'll be able to legally let you take it out of demo mode is said manufacturers.